# translational kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy

Tags: dynamics

In a lever system, are there translational kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy if the center of mass is at the centroid? and If the center of mass changes?

Comment: I think a straight answer to this is possible, but all I have to offer is a side note: the distinction between translational and rotational kinetic energy is somewhat artificial, rotational kinetic energy is just what you get by adding up the translational kinetic energies of all the little bits of an object that is not moving uniformly.